# Why can a simply connected domain in 3D have a hole at the origin?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

Why can a simply connected domain in 3D have a hole at the origin?

It's not hard to think of a path around the origin, and laying in a plane through the origin in 3D.  How can we then "shrink" such a path to a point if the origin is not part of the domain?

Shouldn't we run into the same problem we have in the case of a 2D domain with a hole at the origin?

I'm clearly misunderstand something in the definition of a simply connected domain!

Comment: You don't have to restrict your "shrinking" to that plane.

Comment: You can go "over" the origin in 3D, but not 2D (over as in over the top of).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you mean, we are allowed to "translate" the path into another parallel plane (not including the origin) and perform the shrinking there?

Comment: But doesn't that change the path?  The motion will no longer be passing through the same points in 3D.

Comment: @Triatticus Ah, that makes sense.  So, basically, we can perform whatever transformation we want on the path (as long as we don't require an extra dimension to perform it)?

Comment: You can do any continuous deformation of the loop, even if that requires going into higher dimensions.  As long as you can make any loop deform continuously to a point, then you've shown that the space is simply connected.

Comment: You can **continuously** deform the loop however much you like, just so long as you leave one point (the base of the loop) fixed.  My general mental trick for dealing with loops in this space is to first send the loop to the sphere via the straight line homotopy, then shrink that loop to a point on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: This is why terms like "shrinking" shouldn't be used in definitions.  They are potentially ambiguous.  What the definition didn't say is what it meant by shrinking...  Thanks.  It's slowly starting to make sense.

Comment: One way I've seen this explained:  (Possibly up to small circular arc deformations of your (wildly convoluted) loop to avoid a regular neighborhood of this line) there is a line through the origin that does not intersect your loop.  Pick a point, $p$, on that line in the space.  Every point in the loop can see $p$ -- i.e., each point lies along a ray from $p$ not through the origin.  Now crush your loop back along these rays onto $p$.

Comment: Note that a loop need not lie in the plane.  It need not be particularly "nice" either.  For instance, $(\sin \theta, \cos \theta, \sin(2 \theta))$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ does not lie in any plane.  Very mildly not nice: $(\sin \theta + \frac{1}{2}\sin(10 \theta), \cos \theta + \frac{1}{2}\cos(11 \theta), \sin(2 \theta) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(12 \theta)$.  ![Parametric plot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JbGN4.png), ![Parametric plot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOr7.png), which can be used as a stereoscopic pair.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, in fact, I don't think we should have used "path", as that gives the false idea (at least to me) of what was meant by "shrinking".  The term "loop" makes this much more sensible to me.  A loop can indeed be deformed in a lot more ways than what is general meant by a path, and still remain a loop (especially from a topological stand point).  Thanks for all the effort, I believe I get t now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply connected refers to closed loops that can be contracted. In your case, such a loop can be contracted to a point in 3D no matter where you position the loop. Not so in 2D. The generalization you are thinking of is that of a closed surface: in your case you cannot contract just any closed surface in 3D. If a closed surface wraps around the hole at the origin it cannot be contracted to a point. But "simply connected" refers to curves and not surfaces. There are higher dimensional analogs of simply connected just the way you are thinking.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group

Comment: So this has to do with topology... I never would have guessed from the way it was defined in my textbook.  It says: "*a simply-connected region is a region where any closed curve contained
in it can be continuously shrunk to a point without leaving the region*."     This is not exactly describing what you've just wrote!  Thanks.